# Pre-requisite to analyze classical music

Tags: classical-music, analysis, books

First, I'm sorry for my poor English.

I enjoy listening to classical music.

According to Schiff's analysis of Beethoven's Sonata, It seems that classical music has a certain form, so if any note changes, there is a contradiction in the musical structure within a few bars.

I want to not only appreciate the works but also understand why they should be compose like that.

While majoring in physics mathematics in a non-English speaking country, I got a lot of help from Stack Exchange in book recommendation and detailed explanation about systematic studies.

Can you recommend books or open courseware for detailed analysis of classical music works?

Comment: Do you play an instrument?  Can you read music?

Comment: When I was young, I played Czeny, so I know how to read sheet music, but I don't know basic theories like theory of harmony

Answer (score 1):

All music,and the 'classical' style in particular, is based on elements of repetition and of variation.  It's not really true than changing one note will bring the whole edifice tumbling down! But I sort of see what you're getting at.  If writing a fugue, for instance, where each voice states the theme in turn, it would be odd to capriciously vary one of the entries.

As you mention Beethoven, perhaps you would enjoy 'A companion to Beethoven's Pianoforte Sonatas' by Donald Tovey.  There seem to be plenty of second-hand copies on Amazon and eBay.

Comment: Thanks, I checked the book, but I can't understand the bar by bar analysis because I don't have prior knowledge on music theory. So I want to learn basic music theory systematically and read the book you recommended. Can you recommend a basic music theory book and curriculum?